# How Sync between replica sets in mongoDB achieved. Automatic or Manual triggering Needed?

Tags: mongodb

Going through MongoDB documentation I missed clarity regarding the above question. Please provide commands if any , are used for manual triggering a sync among replica sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replica sets are always automatically synced, but if you need to do a manual re-sync you have a couple of options as explained here https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/

So basically you can stop the member you want to re-sync and empty its data directory. When you will restart it, Mongo will automatically start the sync process.

> 1. Stop the member’s mongod instance. To ensure a clean shutdown, use the db.shutdownServer() method from the mongo shell or on Linux systems, the mongod --shutdown option.
> 2. Delete all data and sub-directories from the member’s data directory. By removing the data dbPath, MongoDB will perform a complete resync. Consider making a backup first.

Another way MongoDB suggests is that you can copy the data from another member, done that MongoDB will start syncing the rest of the data with the master. Similar to the first solution but faster because you have some data yet and you don't need to start from scratch.